# Is it bad practice to keep session objects in the db?

Tags: java, database

I recently read that a REST api should not use sessions because it is then no longer stateless. I was wondering if it is bad practice to have a db table dedicated to storing a session (as opposed to the more common cookie approach). If so why is that bad practice and what problems would it lead to?

Comment: Performance.  Managing stale session data.

Comment: The idea of a stateless REST API is that every client, no matter of the previous request could do a new request. So that means if your API is session based and your client e.g. crashes etc. you must handle all these cases.

Comment: I think why REST should be stateless is clear from Daniels's response. About why DB over Cookie (cases where you need to maintain session) - Keeping all of the session data in cookie makes it heavy, thus adding to the overall response times (more data, more time). If you store session data in DB (I would prefer a distributed cache), you only send and receive a state marker Id in your request/responses thus keeping the payload light. Also, if you are not encrypting your cookie data, it is exposed to the users. Keeping it in the DB makes it unavailable to them.